# Getting nth element from a list of floats

Tags: ocaml, ml

If I have a list of floats:

```
let float_list = [1.5,2.5,3.5]
```

I'm looking to extract a number from this list similar to:

```
List.nth float_list 2
```

However what is returned is type float * float and not 3.5. List.nth only seems to return integers from an integer list and I can't seem to find a function in https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html to return the nth element of any list other than an integer list.

Would anyone be able to help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `float_list` isn't a list of floats, it's a list of `float * float * float` tuples and it only contains one such tuple. So in addition to not having the type you want, `List.nth float_list 2` will actually cause an exception at run time because `2` is not a valid index for that list.

You want `[1.5; 2.5; 3.5]`, which is actually a list of floats. With that list `List.nth` will work exactly as you want.

Answer (score 1):

List literals in OCaml use `;` to separate items. `,` is used to separate items in tuples. So the type of `float_list` is actually `(float * float * float) list`, and it contains only a single element.